# Checking If I understood this concept right (associativity)

Tags: c, associativity

I have the following expression in C. I'm asked whether we can predict the value of z

```
int x,y,z;
z= (x=2) + (y=x)
```

I know that the () operator has left associativity. Does this mean that the left parenthesis will be evaluated before the ones on the right?

I'm trying to understand if I got this concept correctly

Thanks in advance

Comment: not an expert but the expression seems to miss a sequence point.

Comment: I'm not sure parentheses have associativity in the first place.

Comment: There's an associativity/precedence table. Parentheses have the highest level of precedence and left-to-right associativity

Comment: why would you bother to try to figure out what is the output of such an horrible code? Shoot the guy who wrote it, and rewrite it properly.

Comment: Because ot's an exercise to understand how the compiler works

Comment: Good programming avoids the compiler having to make any such decisions.  Such code is of negative use to future SO users/visitors..

Comment: Parentheses in a precedence table represent the *function call operator*, which does have a meaningful precedence. The high precedence of `()` is why `*f()` means `*(f())` instead of `(*f)()`

Comment: @Francisco - The only thing to learn here is never to do this again. *"You can never guess what this code does"* is the opposite of what you do as a professional.

Answer (score 0):

No. Associativity says that `x + (y + z) == (x + y) + z == x + y + z`; the parentheses don't matter when chaining 2 or more of the *same* operator.

In your code, the compiler is free to evaluate the operands of `+` in either order. You don't know if the result will be

```
x=2; y=x; z = x + y;
```

or

```
y=x; x = 2; z + x + y;
```

Comment: But that's the associativity of the addition, not the parentheses, isn't it?

Comment: No, parentheses aren't operators. They group expressions to modify *precedence*, since `z = x = 2 + y = x` would otherwise be parsed as ... I'm not even sure off the top of my head. Maybe `z = (x = (2 + (y = x)))`?